# How can I add additional claims to a Security Token in WCF

Tags: wcf, .net-4.5, wif

I've got a WCF service that takes Security Tokens through the ws2007FederationHttpBinding bindings. This works fine and in my services I can use the following code to get information about the user that was passed across in the token.

```
 var claimsPrincipal = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
 var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)claimsPrincipal.Identity;
 string s;
 foreach (var claim in claimsIdentity.Claims)
 {
         s += "\r\n\t" + claim.Type;
         s += "\r\n\t\t" + claim.Value;
     }
 }
```

I'm sure I've seen somewhere that there is a method I can override in the WCF pipeline to add additional custom claims to the claims identity when the token is read in and before it's saved to ClaimsPrincipal.Current. To give an example as soon as WCF receives this token I want it to go to a custom database lookup the username and add some additional claims.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of what I need to hook in to in order to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Derive from a class called ClaimsAuthenticationManager and register it in . The Authenticate method will be called after the token arrives and before your service is called. Here you can change/add/remove claims.